# Mantener sesion React Redux con JWT

Tags: reactjs, jwt, redux

Estoy trabajando con un backend que esta realizado en python3, y estoy teniendo un problema con los endopoints que me han dado. Ya que al querer mantener la sesion con redux los endpoints que me dan son de peticion POST en lo que respecta al renew/verify token. Y yo deberia verificar con un get que este almacenado en el backend.

He encontrado que dentro del mismo endpoint con el que hago el login, hay un item 'refresh'.
He tratado de implementarlo pero no me esta manteniendo la informacion del usuario.

A continuacion mi codigo de auth y fetch:

auth.js

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import { fetchConToken, fetchSinToken } from '../helpers/fetch';
import { types } from '../types/types';

export const startLogin = (email, password) => {
    return async( dispatch ) => {

        const resp = await fetchSinToken( 'users/login/', { email, password }, 'POST' );
        const body = await resp.json();
        
        if(body.message) {
            localStorage.setItem('token', body.access);
            localStorage.setItem('token-init-date', new Date().getTime());
           

        
            dispatch( login({
                user_id: body.authenticatedUser.user_id,
                name: body.authenticatedUser.first_name,
                email: body.authenticatedUser.email
            }) )
        } else {
            Swal.fire('Error', body.message, 'error');
        }
    }
}

export const startChecking = () => {
    return async(dispatch) => {

        const resp = await fetchConToken( 'users/login/');
        const body = await resp.json();

        if(body.message) {
            localStorage.setItem('token', body.refresh);
            localStorage.setItem('token-init-date', new Date().getTime());
            
            //info del usuario
        dispatch( login({
            user_id: body.authenticatedUser.user_id,
            name: body.authenticatedUser.first_name,
            email: body.authenticatedUser.email
        }))
      
        } else {
            dispatch( checkingFinish());
        }      
    } 
}

const checkingFinish = () => ({ type: types.authCheckingFinish })


const login = ( user ) => ({
    type: types.authLogin,
    payload: user
})
```

fetch

```
const fetchSinToken = (endpoint, data, method = 'GET') => {

    const url = `${ baseUrl }/${ endpoint }`;

    if (method === 'GET') {
        return fetch( url );
    } else {
        return fetch(
            url, {
            method,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
                
            },
            body: JSON.stringify( data )
        });
    } }

const fetchConToken = (endpoint, data, method = 'GET') => {

    const url = `${ baseUrl }/${ endpoint }`;
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token') || '';

    
    if (method === 'GET') {
        return fetch( url );
    } else {
        return fetch(
            url, {
            method,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                
            },
            body: JSON.stringify( data )
        });
    } }

export {
    fetchSinToken,
    fetchConToken }
```

el endopoint users/login muestra lo siguiente:
[image: users/login]

luego tengo un endopoint que es /auth/refresh-token/
que solo trae el token pero no es una peticion Get sino POST...

como podria hacer para mantener la sesion del usuario?